# Body onclick consecutive links

Tags: javascript, onclick

Hi I have this script that opens a new tab when clicking anywhere on the page but it works with only one link, I would like to make it so it can open links multiple times, consecutively. I would really appreciate any help.

```
<script type='text/javascript'>

    var popup = function() {

        window.open (&quot;https://example.com/&quot;, &quot;Window&quot;,&quot;status=1,toolbar=1,width=500,height=500,resizable=yes&quot;);

    }

</script>
```

```
  <body onclick='popup();'>
```

I tried multiples onclick in the body tag but it didn't work

Answer (score 0):

If you want to cycle through multiple URLs, try this out.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <body onclick='popup();'>
    <script>
      const urls = ["https://www.google.com", "https://www.stackoverflow.com", "https://www.gmail.com"];
      let counter = 0;

      const popup = () => {
        window.open(urls[counter++ % urls.length]);
      }
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```